# How to retrieve dynamic fields in SolrNet 3.6?

Tags: solr, solrnet

We are working on ASP.NET MVC3 C# with SolrNet 3.6.
We have used dynamic fields.Solr index has been created successfully with appropriate data and it is working perfectly in Solr Admin as well as in our application also without dynamic fields.
We have retrieved all static fields like Id,Name etc using QueryOption and all that.

But We don't know how to retrieve dynamic fields?

So please suggest us how to retrieve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Accessing Dynamic fields with SolrNet is pretty straight forward. Here is an example of mapping a set of dynamic string fields:

The following field is defined in the schema.xml

```
 <field name="dynamicFields_*" fieldType="string" stored="true" indexed="true" />
```

Then let's assume that you have indexed documents with the following fields:

```
dynamicFields_item1
dynamicFields_item2
```

You would then add the following property to your C# class:

```
 public class IndexItem
 {
    ...

    [SolrField("dynamicFields_")]
    Dictionary<string, string> DynamicFields { get; set;}

    ....
 }
```

Then once you have queried Solr and have an IndexItem class, you can access the dynamic data fields like this:

```
//already have gotten the indexItem before here

 var item1Value = indexItem.DynamicFields["item1"];
 var item2Value = indexItem.DynamicFields["item2"];
```

Hopefully this will help you get dynamic fields working in your code...

Comment: I'm using Solr 4.0 and struggling with an error. I've implemented same as you suggest. Error is :Object of type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' cannot be converted to type 'System.String'. What could be the Problem??? Is is related to newer version of solr or what?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Luke Handler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LukeRequestHandler) to retrieve all the indexed fields (and more) - static and dynamic.  For eg. 
`http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/luke` .

Comment: You have to change the SolrQueryExecutor for that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393700/how-we-changes-standard-query-handler