# How we changes standard query handler

Tags: solrnet

I am using solrnet I have created a new handler and want to change standard query handler "select" to "new" without using any extra parameter like "qt" or defType.

**Currently** 
"http://localhost:8080/solr/select?q=*:*"

**Want**
"http://localhost:8080/solr/new?q=*:*"

Please advise me this is possible or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The post [Changing Handler Endpoint in SolrQueryExecutor](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/solrnet/handler/solrnet/Kqxn68pU0uo/uG50WSxu_swJ) in the [SolrNet Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/solrnet) states that in order to do this you will need to modify the SolrQueryExecutor as described:

> **Question:** On our Solr instance we have changed the search endpoint from "/ 
>   select" to "/search". I see in SolrQueryExecuter that there is a 
>   Handler property that just returns the DefaultHandler of  "/select".  Is there any way to change this to use my endpoint?
>
> **Answer:** That's correct, you need to change that property in SolrQueryExecuter.
>   How you do that depends on your IoC container. For example, with the built-in container you'd Remove() ISolrQueryExecuter and add your own with the changed handler property.
>   This is a quite rare thing to do, usually I just set up different request handlers not as endpoints but as regular names, then you can use the qt parameter to select one.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to invoke a different request handler, you can just get an instance of ISolrQueryExecuter and set the Handler accordingly. No need to replace the built-in SolrQueryExecuter with a concrete decorator.

```
Startup.Init<T>(new SolrConnection("http://localhost:8080/solr")),

var executor = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrQueryExecuter<T>>() as SolrQueryExecuter<T>;
executor.Handler = "/new";
```

BTW, your url seems to be missing the name of the collection.

Answer (score 1):

use the latest version of SolrNet (I used it with .net 4.6).
Define a new RequestHandlerParameters in your QueryOptions like following:

```
using CommonServiceLocator;
using SolrNet;
using SolrNet.Commands.Parameters;

Startup.Init<MwDoc>("http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore");
var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<MyClass>>();

QueryOptions options = new QueryOptions()
            {
                RequestHandler = new RequestHandlerParameters("/new"),
                // define your other Options here
            };
solr.Query("keyword to search", options);
```